# How to use regex in php?

Tags: php, regex

I need a pattern that verifies the input field is in the following format.

```
1st char: a, b, c, or d
2nd: 0-9
third: 0-9
4th: 0-9 (optional char)

valid example: a939, c321, d11, c32
invalid: aa939, c1

preg_match('/^[DSFP][0-9]/', $data) // doesn't work :(
```

Comment: because `DSFP` is not `a, b c or d` and you haven't specified a third and fourth character? `/^[abcd][0-9]{2,3}$/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex should be:

```
/^[abcd]\d{2,3}$/i
```

**Explanation:**

```
^       -- matches line start
[abcd]  -- matches one of literal characters a, b, c, d
\d{2,3} -- matches 2 or 3 digits
$       -- matches line end
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain each component of it?

Comment: Sure, adding to to my answer.

Comment: the 'i' means case insensitive?

Comment: Yes that is true `i` is for making it case insensitive.

Answer (score 4):

Just try with following regex:

```
/^[a-d][0-9]{2,3}$/
```

Explanation:

```
[a-d]      - allows letters from `a` to `d`
[0-9]      - allows just one digit - so invalid here
[0-9]{2,3} - allows 2 to 3 digits
```

Comment: I agree with you on the fact that it's not random enough to be random characters, but it's just not what OP requested. Fix is much better. :)

Comment: @anubhava Not anymore ;-)